# Como receber todas as imagens do Firebase Storage e exibir em uma listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase

Tenho várias imagens capturadas via câmera ou galeria que foi upado via app no Firebase Storage, utilizando o Glide consigo exibir imagens, mas só que manualmente(adicionado um a um na mão), e minhas imagens upadas são nomeadas com a datatime. Necessito de um modelo de captura de todas as imagens e exibi-las em uma listview.
Utilizando o snapshot fiz com dados de texto e funcionou. Mas com o storage como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente a API do Firebase não tem um método para listar todos os arquivos de uma referência.

O que você pode fazer (e que eu precisei faer uma vez) foi, a cada upload, eu gravava a url de download da imagem em uma referência no database do Firebase.

Ai quando precisava, eu lia essa referência que tinha todas as URL's e passava para o Glide carregar as imagens.

Comment: Consegui fazer utilizando RecyclerView, como você disse enviar para o database do Firebase a url da foto/imagem criada e upada no storage, depois é só fazer um iteração para capturar todas elas e mostrar na tela. Obrigado pela dica.