# Como mostrar no gridview os dados do firebase Storage usando Picasso?

Tags: android, firebase, gridview, picasso

Bom dia a todos. Minha dúvida é relativa apenas a parte de exibição da imagem do GridView. Vejam os passos que já estão funcionando:

1. Consigo fazer o upload para o Firebase Storage.
2. Cada vez que uma imagem é enviada ao servidor sua uri é salva no Firebase Database.
3. Tenho um GridView exibindo imagens salvas na pasta drawable.
4. O *Firebase Storage* esta corretamente configurado pois consigo pegar uma imagem dele e exibir em uma *ImagemView* atrabés da uri salva no Database.

Ainda não consegui entender como posso fazer o loop no Database e através do Picasso exibir no GridView. Grato a quem possa ajudar.

**Segue o Código do GridView:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();    

private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);




    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

}

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como receber todas as imagens do Firebase Storage e exibir em uma listview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221516/como-receber-todas-as-imagens-do-firebase-storage-e-exibir-em-uma-listview)

Comment: A pergunta não está duplicada pois a minha se refere apenas à parte da visualização no gridview. Na outra não existe essa informação.

Answer (score 0):

A classe que está usando o `ImageAdapter` deve passar as referências das imagens que você carregou do Firebase, substituindo o array `mThumbIds`.